# Jhipster json file not found

Tags: json, spring-boot, jhipster

I created a simple project with jhipster. The back-end is working but in front-end section, I see the error

```
GET  http://localhost:8080/i18n/en/customers.json 404 (Not Found)
```

when I execute *customers.html* page. I can reach JSON data via browser or postman but I did not understand why I see this error. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it. In customer.state.js file, i changed this part according to my pages

```
resolve: {
    translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('customer');
        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('global');
        return $translate.refresh();
    }]
}
```